ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler'
I was trying to run this github project https://github.com/TUMFTM/laptime-simulation, and while trying to install the requirements, it shows me this error " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler' ". PLease help
i installed setup tools too, installed Visual studio

what version of cython you are using

Related question

idk about that, i prompted chatgpt and it told me to install visual studio
